# Memory Leak issue with Monarch social sharing plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, memory-leaks

I've battled with Elegant Themes and WPEngine over this issue now for the past 2 weeks, and I'm getting absolutely nowhere with either of them.

Here is just one of the errors from the log:

```
[Wed Apr 26 20:37:29.797099 2017] [:error] [pid 9802] [client 192.104.203.89:55604] PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 218817933 bytes) in /nas/content/live/amberrein/wp-content/plugins/monarch/monarch.php on line 4279, referer: http://www.amberreinhardt.com/category/weddings/
```

I've already upped the memory limit via wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M' );
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M' );
```

It's very hit or miss with the memory leak. Some blog posts are fine, while others are not. Then, I go back to visit a working post, and then it's not loading because of the leak, so for whatever reason, it changes or something. I don't know. And the memory leak amount is always different, but never higher than what I have the limit set to. But, it also seems that the higher the limit, the longer it takes for a post to load if it does load, which is strange.

here is the entire function that i believe is causing the error. line 4279 starts with `$content`:

function display_media( $content ) {
    $monarch_options = $this->monarch_options;

```
if ( $this->check_applicability( $monarch_options[ 'sharing_media_post_types' ], 'media' ) ) {
    preg_match_all( '/<img [^>]*>/s', $content, $images_array );
    foreach ( $images_array[0] as $image ) {
        if ( false !== strpos( $image, 'class="ngg_' ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        preg_match( '@src="([^"]+)"@' , $image , $image_src );

        $icons       = $this->generate_media_icons( $image_src[1] );
        $replacement = '<div class="et_social_media_wrapper">' . $image . $icons . '</div>';
        $content     = str_replace( $image, $replacement, $content );
    }
}

return $content;
```

}

What can I do to resolve this issue, since Elegant Themes and WPEngine are no help? I don't want to have to disable the plugin as the client wants to keep it.

Comment: I've obviously done that. I've been going back and forth with the developer for over 2 weeks now, with no real results. Not only that, but we've been using the Monarch plugin in conjunction with the Divi theme made by the SAME developer for over 2 years now, and have never ran into this type of issue. Since they obviously cannot supply me with the help that i need, I figured I would reach out here.

Comment: You haven't told us what you've already tried, so you can expect that most suggestions will fall in the category: "I've already tried that.". Have you tried to debug the code yourself? Do you have any debugging experience? The problem is that we cannot reproduce your problem give the code in your question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Finally: What happens if you put `/* .... */` around the loop in the piece of code you show?